# Dealing with javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I have a function in javascript as so :

```
function player(){
    var cards=[];
    this.score=0;
    var self=this;

    this.addCard=addCard;
    this.resetCards=resetCards;


    function addCard(card){

        cards.push(card);
        this.score=+card.value;
    }

    function resetCards(){
        cards=[];
        score=0;
    }


}
```

I user a constructor to call the function :

```
var player1=new player();
```

Then I call some of its enclosed functions like this

```
player1.addCard(someCardObject);//card someCardObject has .value say 5
player1.addCard(someCardObject);//card someCardObject has .value say 7
```

I expect player1.score to be 5+7=12 ,but it stays 7 .

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here

Comment: You never add anything to `.score`.

Comment: doesn't calling addCard add to score ,if not is there a way to make score static

Comment: No, it doesn’t. `this.score = +card.value;` assigns `card.value` — converted to a number — to `this.score`. Did you mean `this.score += card.value;`?

Comment: There is a typo `this.score=+card.value;` which sets the last value to `score`, instead of adding it.

Comment: `+card.value` will act as `Unary plus`.. https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/kjd32p0n/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a simple error in `addCard`.

```
this.score=+card.value;
```

Should be

```
this.score += card.value;
```

In the first instance, you're setting `this.score` equal to `card.value`, while in the second one, you're adding `card.value` to it. Remember kids, order of operators matters!

Comment: That’s not even an issue of order or operations. It’s just a typo.

Comment: Fair point. Changed to "order of operators", which is correct. I just wanted to say something pithy :P

Comment: _" you're incrementing it with card.value"_... That is wrong... [___"Remember kids ?"___]

Comment: Changed the wording a bit to make it more correct.

Comment: `this.score=+card.value;` will first convert/cast any value to "`Number`" and then assign it to `this.score`
.. It is [___`Unary plus (+)`___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())